# Installing Brother scanner MFC-7225N in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, scanner, udev, brother

I tried to install my Brother MFC-7225N scanner in Lubuntu 16.04 64 bit following the instructions [here](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Scanner/Brother/), but I only get the error “Invalid argument”.

### What I did

- install the driver `brscan2-0.2.5-1.amd64.deb` as well as the scan-key-tool `brscan-skey-0.2.4-1.amd64.deb` and the udev rule package `brother-udev-rule-type1-1.0.0-1.all.deb` from [here](http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/download_scn.html)
- add the following lines to `/lib/udev/rules.d/60-libsane.rules`, trying one at a time:

  ```
  ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f9", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0186", MODE="0660", GROUP="scanner", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
  ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f9", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0186", MODE="0664", GROUP="scanner", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
  ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f9", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0186", MODE="0666", GROUP="scanner", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
  ```
- copy files over:

  ```
  sudo cp /usr/lib64/sane/* /usr/lib/sane/
  sudo cp /usr/lib64/libbr* /usr/lib/
  ```
- create `brother.conf` files:

  ```
  echo -e "/usr/lib64\n/usr/lib64/sane" | sudo tee /etc/ld.so.conf.d/brother.conf && sudo ldconfig
  echo "usb 04f9 0186" | sudo tee /etc/sane.d/brother.conf
  ```
- run the setup program:

  ```
  sudo /usr/local/Brother/sane/setupSaneScan2 -i
  ```

### What I get

```
> brscan-skey

> brscan-skey -l
 MFC-7225N         : brother2:bus2;dev1  : USB                  Active

> scanimage -L
device `bus2;dev1' is a Brother MFC-7225N USB scanner

> scanimage -T
scanimage: open of device bus2;dev1 failed: Invalid argument

> simple-scan -d
…
[+5,91s] DEBUG: simple-scan.vala:404: Requesting scan at 300 dpi from device 'bus2;dev1'
[+5,91s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:1560: Scanner.scan ("bus2;dev1", dpi=300, scan_mode=ScanMode.COLOR, depth=8, type=ScanType.SINGLE, paper_width=0, paper_height=0, brightness=0, contrast=0)
[+5,91s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:803: Processing request
[+5,91s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:864: sane_open ("bus2;dev1") -> SANE_STATUS_INVAL
[+5,91s] WARNING: scanner.vala:868: Unable to get open device: Invalid argument
…
```

### Some more information

```
> lsusb
…
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 138a:0017 Validity Sensors, Inc. Fingerprint Reader
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 04f9:0186 Brother Industries, Ltd Composite Device
…

> sudo sane-find-scanner
…
found USB scanner (vendor=0x138a, product=0x0017) at libusb:002:004
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04f9, product=0x0186) at libusb:002:009
could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
…

> cat /etc/sane.d/dll.conf
…
brother2
…

> cat /etc/sane.d/brother.conf
usb 04f9 0186
```

Comment: For me the [Brother Driver Install Tool](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=de&lang=de&prod=mfc7225n_eu&os=128&flang=English) always gave good results: https://askubuntu.com/questions/636363/how-do-i-install-proprietary-drivers-for-my-brother-all-in-one-printer-scanner-f

Comment: I can't test if it works but Brother lists your model. See link above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than downgrading your USB functionality why not consider connecting the [Brother MFC-7225N](https://www.cnet.com/products/brother-mfc-7225n/specs/) via the LAN? That's what I did [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/456061/how-do-i-get-a-brother-dcp-7065dn-printer-working) when I too had difficulty scanning over USB with a Brother DCP-7065DN and it's been working famously ever since. Working with currently supported LTS versions.

Comment: Thanks! I considered this, unfortunately it's currently not an option, but may come in handy later. Am I right “via LAN” means you connect the printer to a router instead of connecting it directly to the computer?

Comment: Yes. You are correct connecting to the router or switch on your network and setting a static IP should resolve the issue entirely. Your model Brother has a LAN port as does mine. Connecting in that fashion eliminated any issues for me.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a unsatisfactory solution by reading [this](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Scanner/Brother/#Problembehandlung) carefully: For me on a Lenovo Thinkpad X240 it's not working with USB 3.0. I **disabled USB 3.0 support in my BIOS** and suddenly it worked just fine. However, of course by doing that **all** USB ports on the machine are just as fast as USB 2.0 now - apparently one has to make a decision here, or be okay with changing the BIOS setting every time one want to scan or rather use USB 3.0 functionality.

Answer (score -1):

This solution [How do I make the scanner function of my Brother DCP-315CN work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91933/how-do-i-make-the-scanner-function-of-my-brother-dcp-315cn-work/129908#129908)
worked for me after upgrading from Ubuntu Mate x32 to x64, installing the brscan drivers from [support.brother.com](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=eu_ot&lang=en&prod=dcp7010_eu_as&os=128#SelectLanguageType-570_0_1) 
and adding the corresponding line to `libsane.rules`

```
sudo cp /usr/lib64/libbrscandec2* /usr/lib
sudo cp /usr/lib64/libbrcolm2* /usr/lib
sudo cp /usr/lib64/sane/libsane-brother2* /usr/lib/sane
```

Comment: Thanks, but my question states that I already tried all of that.